# Is it possible to ban or flag an user rather than his posts?

Tags: feature-request

There's some guy who is a paid writer. He does write very articulated answers, sometimes a bit off topic, but nice nevertheless. However, he uses those answers to spam certain site. He had a first round where he only linked to that site, and we deleted all his spam and/or the entire answer.

Now he is back, this time he spams the same site but adds a link to another site hoping we won't notice one of the links is his usual spam.

Quite honestly, I find it very tedious to chase his misbehavior, and I think it shows very little respect to the community, so I'd ban him or at least flag his answers for review or whatever, but I don't see a mechanism to do so (in StackOverflow he'd be banned already).

Is it possible to implement such a mechanism? Or does it exist and I didn't see it? Or automatically flag the spammed site?

**edit:** just noticed **there are 2 of them**, both spamming the same site, and they usually post on the same questions

Answer (score 1):

I noticed all your flagging of spam today Devin.  Thanks, that was helpful.

Mods can suspend or ban a user, but I only see the possibilities open to mods, not normal users.  As far as I'm aware, there is no way to flag a user.  However, if a mod sees spam from a user, they will typically get a warning or a suspension or be deleted, depending on the spam.  So simply flagging a few of their posts will have a similar effect to flagging a user.